# Should "listening" always be followed by the preposition "to"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, intransitive-verbs

While we always add a preposition *to* with *listen*, as in *listen to music*, does that apply with *listening* as well?

Is the following sentence correct?

> I am habitual of listening this from you ?

Comment: Try asking here: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: _listen` is an intransitive verb. You don't say _listen something, you can only say _listen to someone_ or _listen for something_.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Barmar's answer.  "Listen" is an intransive verb (it doesn't take a direct object) - "Bob is a good student.  He listens."  "Listen to" is a transitive verb, meaning "to hear and mentally process", e.g., "Bob is a good student.  He listens to the teacher."  "Listen for" is also a transitive verb, meaning "to be on a alert for something", e.g. "Bob is a lazy student.  He listens for the bell."

I'm not sure what you mean by your sentence, because "habitual" means you do something over time, but "this" usually refers to a specific instance.  You might say, for instance, "I habitually listen to your podcast."

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Greggo's answer, and in attempt to answer "Is this statement correct" beyond merely the distinction of "listen to" and "listening to", the statement above would still be improper: "I am habitual of listening to this from you" still could be better phrased:

- I habitually listen to this from you (something specific being said)
- I habitually listen to you (listening, in general)
- I am habitually listening to this from you (quite awkward, would prefer #1, but plausible)
- I am habitually listening to you (same comment as above, for #2)

But generally speaking, the answer, as discussed, is "yes" - both 'listen' and 'listening' require a 'to', if you're specify the direct object of the sentence.